# Find page of interactive form field in PDF

Tags: objective-c, forms, pdf

I am trying to build a PDF parser that gives me all the locations and types of interactive form fields. I run through the entries of the AcroForm dictionary and get the right number, types and coordinates of the form fields. But how can I find the page on which a particular field is meant to be drawn? This is the revelant snippet:

```
 NSURL*  pdfURL = [openPanel URL];
    CGPDFDocumentRef pdfDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
    
    CFRelease((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
    
    CGPDFDictionaryRef pdfCatalog = CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog(pdfDocument);
    
    CGPDFDictionaryRef acroForm;
    CGPDFDictionaryGetDictionary(pdfCatalog,"AcroForm",&acroForm);
    
    CGPDFArrayRef formFieldsArray;
    CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(acroForm,"Fields", &formFieldsArray);
    long formFieldsCount = CGPDFArrayGetCount(formFieldsArray);
    
    for (int j = 0; j < formFieldsCount; j++){

        CGPDFDictionaryRef formFieldDictionary;
        CGPDFArrayGetDictionary(formFieldsArray, j, &formFieldDictionary);
```

Comment: Form Fields are represented by zero or more Widget Annotations. So a Field could be on zero, one, or multiple pages. The most reliable way to answer your question is to iterate the Page tree and check the Annots array of each page looking for your Widget Annotations, which you can then get the Field name from.

Comment: Thank you! I now traverse the page tree, grabbing all the Annots for each page and looking at all Widgets. The number Fields for each page is correct. These appear to be terminal fields as they all have 0 children (key "Kids"). But quite a few of the fields do not return no value for the field type (key "FT"). Why would that be? The PDF spec says that FT is required for terminal fields.

Comment: It is an inheritable field, so the FT key could be located higher up the tree.

Comment: Works! Parent fields contain the FT key (and value) in those cases where the terminal fields do not yield a result themselves. Thanks man!